# exponential curve fitting with 3 coefficients

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, exponential

I have some data (two same size vectors X and Y) and would like to fit an exponential function as `f(x)=a+(b-a)*exp(-c*x)` to this data by MATLAB. My goal is actually to find  coefficients a, b and c.

I found `fit(X,Y,'exp2')` and `fit(X,Y,'exp1','StartPoint',[x0,y0])` in MATLAB manual which are a little different than what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can fit using a [custom equation](http://mathworks.com/help/curvefit/custom-nonlinear-models.html#bs5cxl7-1):

```
f = fit(x, y, 'a+(b-a)*exp(-c*x)')
```

Comment: Thanks! I did it, but got a warning about start point which is chosen randomly! This is the message:

Warning: Start point not provided, choosing random start
point. 
> In Warning>Warning.throw at 30
  In fit>iFit at 299
  In fit at 108

Comment: @Amir did you read the linked documentation? you can specify the start point using  `fit(x, y, 'a+(b-a)*exp(-c*x)', 'StartPoint',[x0,y0])`

Comment: Yes. But I'm not sure about choosing a point or which point of my data set. Is it like just a helpful point for making interpolation quicker (like an initial guess for iterations)? Or it can affect the resulted function and is important?

Answer (score 1):

One great thing that you can do is to use the "Curve fitting" App in Matlab. you can find it in APPS,  in "Math, statistics and optimization" section.

over there you can choose your x and y data and the function that you want to fit over them (exponential or even custom).

Then you can see the fitting results on a plot, also, fitting parameters are shown.

If you were satisfied with the results and you want to use them inside a code, simply hit the generate code under the File tab.
[Curve fitting app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRAMe.png)

you can see the details in this screenshot i took.
after pressing the generate code button, matlab will create a fuction that will give the same result.
what i like to do is just copy the parts i need in this case:

```
     enter code here
     [xData, yData] = prepareCurveData( x, y );

     % Set up fittype and options.
    ft = fittype( 'a +(b-a)*exp(-c*x)', 'independent', 'x', 'dependent', 'y' );
    opts = fitoptions( 'Method', 'NonlinearLeastSquares' );
    opts.Display = 'Off';
    opts.StartPoint = [0.957166948242946 0.485375648722841 0.8002804688888];

    % Fit model to data.
    [fitresult, gof] = fit( xData, yData, ft, opts );
```

as you can see matlab adds the necessary details and now you can access fitting parameters using fitresult. for example-> fitresult.a